# jQuery add same class to same element index in two different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing, carousel

I am using a carousel jquery plugin that doesn't have a built in thumbnail nav, so I am trying to build a poor-man's version.

I'm using the Owl Carousel plugin.

So what I need, for this instance, to happen is that if a slide div in the main carousel has a class .active, then I need to have a div in the second carousel, which has the same index, to get a class active.

Main carousel code:

```
    <div id="slide1">
        <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
            <div class="owl-wrapper">
               <div class="owl-item"></div>
               <div class="owl-item active"></div>
               <div class="owl-item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then here is the carousel which I am using as a nav:

```
<div id="slide2">
   <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
       <div class="owl-wrapper">
           <div class="owl-item"></div>
           <div class="owl-item"></div>  <!-- this should automatically get .active added -->
           <div class="owl-item"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure how to get the index of both elements, then add class active to #slide2 so that they match.

Ok, here is an update, thanks to the code provided by Michael Schmuki. I added this code to a function that is already being used when the slide moves.. and it works.. however, in my slideshow for #slide1, it shows two slides at once. The good thing is is that both of these slides have the active class added automatically, but when I added in this code, only one of the thumbnails in #slide2 get the active class. Is there a reason it isn't picking up both active slides?

Here's the part of the function I'm using:

```
function animateIn(carousel){
  var carousel = $('#slide1');
  var nthChildActive = $(this).find(".active").index() + 1;
  $('#slide2 .owl-item .slide.active').removeClass('active');
  $("#slide2 .owl-wrapper .owl-item:nth-child("+nthChildActive+")").addClass("active");
}
```

And here is where it is set up in Owl Carousel

```
carousel.owlCarousel({
  items: 2,
   pagination:false,
   stopOnHover:true,
   afterMove: function() {
     animateIn();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Show us your Javascript code.

Comment: jquery.each() makes the element index its first callback argument. You can use that to navigate the elements in #slide2 by using $('#slide2 .owl-item').eq(index);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect and mark the (multiple) active elements like this:

```
//detect & mark
$("#slide1 .owl-item").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).hasClass("active"))
    $("#slide2 .owl-item:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").addClass("active");
});
```

You can play with the new example on http://jsbin.com/oHOyEZi/7/edit?js,output

But I'm not familiar with Owl Carousel, so you have to figure out by yourself how to specify, that this logic will be fired when the carousel actually slides.

Comment: So for owl carousel, I can add a function to what is labelled afterMove. I'll add the code in an edit to my original post. If you have any pointers for that, that would be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: So I used your code and it does work, but is there a reason why it is only picking up one of the divs that has class active from #slide1? I edited my original post and mentioned that 2 slides show at once, and both have the .active class set from #slide1.

Comment: I've just edited my snipped to detect multiple elements with the class "active". Have a look at http://jsbin.com/oHOyEZi/7/edit?js,output And yes, afterMove seems legit

Comment: I marked yours as correct, since it answered the original question, but if you have any thoughts about my follow up, that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but what is your follow up? Note that i edited my original answer & the snippet..

Comment: Ahhhhhhh sorry I didn't see that edit. Works like a charm! Thanks!